# C# Multiple Keystroke inputs without overlapping

Tags: c#, multithreading, keystroke

I'm making a game in C# (It's a pong game) and I've completed an "AI" so you can play 1 player, and I've also done a Multiplayer version, but, whenever someone hits a key (up or down) the other players' movement stops, and so on.

So basically you can't play 2 players because it would interrupt the other players movement. I am not sure what I need to do (Multithreading?) or some other kind of thing so that you can have a fluid play and not overlap the other players keystrokes.

I can't really search (even though i have) because i wouldn't know what to search for. :)

Anyways, hope there is a way hehe.

C# Form application (with tutorila game engine/library).

Comment: You need to post some code. Do you know what is blocking the other player?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear enough, the blocking happens when a new Keystroke is made. I'll post my method and some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are relying on the keyboard controller repeating the key when you hold it down.  Yes, that stops working when you press another key.

The standard game loop approach is to use the KeyDown event to set a key-is-down flag and use the KeyUp event to reset it.  Then in your game loop you check that flag and move the paddle when the flag is set.  You could also pinvoke GetAsyncKeyState().

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're playing on the same PC.

When one key is pressed you'll need to perform those actions in a separate thread, otherwise the other players key presses will be blocked by that thread until it finishes executing.

What I assume is happening:

Player 1: hold down <--

Player 2: holds down A

Player 1: the <-- is not being registered anymore

You'll need to be able to determine when a key is pressed, and when it is let go. Having it pressed should tell your application "this key pressed" = true. When released, it is now false. This way you're not mapping to the keyboard itself, but to objects within your application, and the events fired off of the key down / up change those settings.

Doing so would allow you to hold down <-, then hold ->, release <- and have your -> take action by moving right.

Comment: This is not working, as even though its just true/false the very action of changing that seems to stop the paddles from moving.,